About some conditions that guarantee that $f:X\times\mathbb{R}\to Y$, with $Y$ being an arbitrary metric space, is measurable
Consider the following lemma taken from the book "Measure Theory" written V.I. Bogachev (see pg 16 of the volume 2):

6.4.6. Lemma. Suppose that $(X,\mathfrak{B})$ is a measurable space and a function $f:X\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
the following conditions: for every fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the
function $x\mapsto f(x,t)$ is $\mathfrak{B}$-measurable, and for every
fixed $x\in X$, the function $t\mapsto f(x,t)$ is right-continuous.
Then, the function $f$ is measurable with respect to
$\mathfrak{B}\otimes\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, $f$ may be a
mapping with values in a separable metric space.

As you can see, the author says that the lemma is also true if the function $f$ takes value on a separable metric space. My question is: is that lemma false for non-separable metric space?
I think that the previous lemma is true for all metric space (even for arbitrary perfect normal spaces) because of the following lemma (see pg 11 of the book):

6.2.5. Lemma. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $T$ be a metric space (or, more generally, a perfectly normal
space, i.e., a space in which every closed set is the set of zeros of
a continuous function). A mapping $f:\Omega\to T$ is measurable with
respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}(T)$
precisely when for every continuous real function $\psi$ on $T$, the
function $\psi\circ f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$.

Am I right?
Thank you for your attention!
